# MATLAB - ENUM - Cannot call the constructor of 'X' outside of its enumeration block

Tags: matlab, constructor, enums

I am trying to create an enum just like this:

```
classdef MoleculeType < media.Molecule
    enumeration
        O2 (media.ElementalComposition(media.Atom(media.AtomicWeight.Oxygen), int32(2)))
    end

end
```

Inherited Molecule Class:

```
classdef Molecule < handle

    properties(SetAccess = immutable)

        chemicalComposition

    end

    ...

    methods

        function obj = Molecule(composition)
            obj.chemicalComposition = composition;
        end

    ...

    end

    ...

end
```

When I try to get an instance from MoleculeType, I get **"Cannot call the constructor of 'media.MoleculeType' outside of its enumeration block."** error.
I couldn't figure out where it tries to call MoleculeType constructor so I get this error, because there is no reference to MoleculeType constructor in my code.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Hint: I created enum classes without error before and they were having primitive values inside (e.g. `O2(32)`). Problem arise when I try to use object types inside enumerations (like in this question: `O2(media.ElementalComposition)`). I searched this in MATLAB documentation, there is no example. Documentation neither provide an example nor say that it is not supported.

Comment: found a link here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18997-simulink-enumeration   how did you get the instance?

Comment: What instance? What do you mean?

Comment: Most likely `MoleculeType` can't see the other classes.  Make sure everything is `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you trying to create the enum instance? The following works for me, unless I construct it the wrong way at the command line:

**Molecule.m (Simplified)**

```
classdef Molecule
    properties(SetAccess=immutable)
        Composition
    end
    methods
        function m = Molecule(composition)
            m.Composition = composition;
        end
    end
end
```

**MoleculeType.m**

```
classdef MoleculeType < Molecule
    enumeration
        O2 (32)
    end
end
```

**Creating/referencing the enum**

```
>> MoleculeType % wrong way
Error using MoleculeType
Cannot call the constructor of 'MoleculeType' outside of its enumeration block.

>> MoleculeType.O2 % right way

ans = 

    O2

>>
```

Hope that helps!